# Grant type/flow to use for multitenant application

Tags: c#, authentication, openid

Let's image we have a multitenant(organization) application having a separate database per tenant(organization).

The core of the application is a REST api service protected by an authorization server, in this case Identity Server 4.

For administration purposes a user can login into an administration panel with a username and password using hybrid flow. After successfull authorization the issued tokens can be used against the API for the user to authorize and based on its organization to create a DB context for the correct database. So far, so good.

Now we need an application(SPA) to be able to authenticate on behalf of a user (without user interaction) to the same API service so the API service to be able to create the correct DB context as in the administration application. 
Here comes the question - what authorization flow to use for this operation?
At first I decided to use the ROPC(Resource Owner Password Credentials) but after reading a couple of articles and OIDC specs it is generally not recommended. For reference - [Why the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type is not Authentication nor Suitable for Modern Applications](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

So the key point here is that we need to authenticate on behalf of a user, but without its interaction, so we can connect to the correct organization database.
The client application can and will be fully trusted from API service.

I am really stucked on this one and cannot decide what way to go on.

Comment: Is there a particular requirement why you're using user credentials to connect to the database? Other than this not really being done anymore, it also suggests that you're intentionally deferring user access management to the database server, at which point it makes no sense for your application to want to manage-but-also-not-manage the user's access. You're writing a gatekeeper with no authority, which sounds like an exercise in futility.

Comment: @Flater, I am not using user credentials to connect to the database - based on the logged in user I am able to determine to which organiaztion this user belongs, the organization has some details like name, server, etc. and then using these details I am able to creare a new dynamic DB context. This is a pretty standard concept when creating a multitenant applications.
Here the user is the only entity which could be authenticated and that's why the whole precess starts from its login.